# Find a list of users with the same set of permission groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

We are adding Roles to our system for our security setup.

We are trying take our main UserItems table to find a list of users with the same set of permission groups so that we can suggest to the end user what roles should be setup and with what permission groups.

Here is the table setup:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserItems](
    [UserItemId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PermissionGroupId] [int] NULL,
    [CanModify] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ItemOrganizationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SortOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserItemId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I've tried several SQL statements, I'm having no luck.

I'm trying to obtain a list of users with the same set of permission groups, so we can determine possible roles based on what the customer has set up for the UserItems.

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS TotalUsers, dbo.UserItems.PermissionGroupId,      dbo.PermissionGroups.PermissionGroupName
     FROM            dbo.UserItems INNER JOIN
                         dbo.PermissionGroups ON dbo.UserItems.PermissionGroupId =    dbo.PermissionGroups.PermissionGroupId
    GROUP BY  dbo.UserItems.PermissionGroupId,  dbo.PermissionGroups.PermissionGroupName
    HAVING        (COUNT(*) > 1)
    ORDER BY TotalUsers DESC


    SELECT        COUNT(*) AS TotalUsers,  dbo.UserEndItems.PermissionGroupId
FROM            dbo.UserItems
    Group by dbo.UserItems.PermissionGroupId
    HAVING        (COUNT(*) > 1)
    ORDER BY TotalUsers DESC
```

How can I obtain a list of users with the same set of permissions groups so that we can make roles based on that data?

| UserItemId | UserId | PermissionGroupId | CanModify | ItemOrganizationId | SortOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 228 | 420 | 1 | 5001 | 4 |
| 2 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 4395 | 5 |
| 3 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 5152 | 5 |
| 4 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 5154 | 5 |
| 5 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 4861 | 5 |
| 6 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 4394 | 5 |
| 7 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 4442 | 0 |
| 8 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 5102 | 5 |
| 9 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 5100 | 5 |
| 10 | 228 | 419 | 0 | 4145 | 5 |
| 11 | 228 | 420 | 0 | 4102 | 0 |
| 12 | 228 | 423 | 0 | 4112 | 0 |
| 13 | 228 | 419 | 0 | 4098 | 0 |
| 14 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 15 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 5785 | 3 |
| 16 | 228 | 499 | 0 | 6617 | 0 |
| 17 | 228 | 499 | 0 | 6619 | 0 |
| 18 | 228 | 499 | 0 | 6621 | 0 |
| 19 | 228 | 499 | 0 | 6623 | 0 |
| 20 | 107 | 499 | 1 | 6617 | 0 |
| 21 | 107 | 499 | 0 | 6619 | 0 |
| 22 | 107 | 499 | 0 | 6621 | 0 |
| 23 | 107 | 499 | 0 | 6623 | 0 |
| 24 | 228 | 426 | 0 | 6970 | 0 |
| 25 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 4395 | 0 |
| 26 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 5152 | 0 |
| 27 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 5154 | 0 |
| 28 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 4861 | 0 |
| 29 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 4394 | 0 |
| 30 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 4442 | 0 |
| 31 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 5102 | 0 |
| 32 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 5100 | 0 |
| 33 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 34 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 5785 | 0 |
| 35 | 108 | 426 | 0 | 6970 | 0 |
| 36 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 4395 | 0 |
| 37 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 5152 | 0 |
| 38 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 5154 | 0 |
| 39 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 4861 | 0 |
| 40 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 4394 | 0 |
| 41 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 4442 | 0 |
| 42 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 5102 | 0 |
| 43 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 5100 | 0 |
| 44 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 45 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 5785 | 0 |
| 46 | 137 | 426 | 0 | 6970 | 0 |
| 47 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 4395 | 0 |
| 48 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 5152 | 0 |
| 49 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 5154 | 0 |
| 50 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 4861 | 0 |
| 51 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 4394 | 0 |
| 52 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 4442 | 0 |
| 53 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 5102 | 0 |
| 54 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 5100 | 0 |
| 55 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 56 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 5785 | 0 |
| 57 | 107 | 426 | 0 | 6970 | 0 |
| 58 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 4395 | 0 |
| 59 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 5152 | 0 |
| 60 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 5154 | 0 |
| 61 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 4861 | 0 |
| 62 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 4394 | 0 |
| 63 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 4442 | 0 |
| 64 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 5102 | 0 |
| 65 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 5100 | 0 |
| 66 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 67 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 5785 | 0 |
| 68 | 235 | 426 | 0 | 6970 | 0 |
| 69 | 228 | 442 | 0 | 5738 | 0 |
| 70 | 228 | 442 | 0 | 5741 | 0 |
| 71 | 107 | 531 | 0 | 7111 | 0 |
| 72 | 107 | 531 | 0 | 7113 | 0 |
| 73 | 107 | 531 | 0 | 7115 | 0 |
| 74 | 107 | 531 | 0 | 7117 | 0 |
| 75 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 6970 | 0 |
| 76 | 222 | 531 | 0 | 7111 | 0 |
| 77 | 222 | 531 | 0 | 7113 | 0 |
| 78 | 222 | 531 | 0 | 7115 | 0 |
| 79 | 222 | 531 | 0 | 7117 | 0 |
| 80 | 222 | 499 | 0 | 6617 | 0 |
| 81 | 222 | 499 | 0 | 6619 | 0 |
| 82 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 5785 | 0 |
| 83 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 4394 | 0 |
| 84 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 4395 | 0 |
| 85 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 4442 | 0 |
| 86 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 4861 | 0 |
| 87 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 5100 | 0 |
| 88 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 5102 | 0 |
| 89 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 5152 | 0 |
| 90 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 5154 | 0 |
| 91 | 222 | 499 | 0 | 6623 | 0 |
| 92 | 222 | 499 | 0 | 6621 | 0 |
| 93 | 222 | 426 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 94 | 228 | 421 | 0 | 4983 | 0 |
| 95 | 228 | 421 | 0 | 4225 | 0 |
| 96 | 228 | 421 | 0 | 4142 | 0 |
| 97 | 228 | 421 | 0 | 4285 | 0 |
| 98 | 228 | 421 | 0 | 4144 | 0 |
| 99 | 228 | 421 | 0 | 4141 | 0 |
| 100 | 228 | 421 | 0 | 4099 | 0 |
| 101 | 228 | 421 | 1 | 5973 | 0 |
| 102 | 228 | 424 | 0 | 4112 | 0 |
| 103 | 228 | 424 | 0 | 4102 | 0 |
| 104 | 228 | 424 | 0 | 4095 | 0 |
| 105 | 228 | 424 | 0 | 4101 | 0 |
| 106 | 228 | 424 | 0 | 4099 | 0 |
| 107 | 228 | 424 | 0 | 4096 | 0 |
| 108 | 228 | 424 | 0 | 4098 | 0 |
| 109 | 228 | 424 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 110 | 228 | 424 | 0 | 4579 | 0 |
| 111 | 228 | 424 | 0 | 4586 | 0 |
| 112 | 228 | 418 | 0 | 4579 | 0 |
| 113 | 228 | 418 | 0 | 5443 | 0 |
| 114 | 107 | 499 | 0 | 5784 | 0 |
| 115 | 222 | 499 | 0 | 5784 | 0 |
| 116 | 197 | 418 | 0 | 4579 | 0 |
| 117 | 197 | 418 | 0 | 5443 | 0 |
| 118 | 197 | 419 | 0 | 4145 | 0 |
| 119 | 197 | 419 | 0 | 4098 | 0 |
| 120 | 197 | 420 | 0 | 5001 | 0 |
| 121 | 197 | 420 | 0 | 4102 | 0 |
| 122 | 197 | 421 | 0 | 5973 | 0 |
| 123 | 197 | 421 | 0 | 4141 | 0 |
| 124 | 197 | 421 | 0 | 4983 | 0 |
| 125 | 197 | 421 | 0 | 4099 | 0 |
| 126 | 197 | 421 | 0 | 4142 | 0 |
| 127 | 197 | 421 | 0 | 4144 | 0 |
| 128 | 197 | 421 | 0 | 4225 | 0 |
| 129 | 197 | 421 | 0 | 4285 | 0 |
| 130 | 197 | 423 | 0 | 4112 | 0 |
| 131 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4586 | 0 |
| 132 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4579 | 0 |
| 133 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4112 | 0 |
| 134 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 135 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4099 | 0 |
| 136 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4098 | 0 |
| 137 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4135 | 0 |
| 138 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4095 | 0 |
| 139 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4096 | 0 |
| 140 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4106 | 0 |
| 141 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4102 | 0 |
| 142 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4100 | 0 |
| 143 | 197 | 424 | 0 | 4101 | 0 |
| 144 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 5102 | 0 |
| 145 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 5152 | 0 |
| 146 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 5154 | 0 |
| 147 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 5100 | 0 |
| 148 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 4442 | 0 |
| 149 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 4394 | 0 |
| 150 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 4395 | 0 |
| 151 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 5785 | 0 |
| 152 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 4861 | 0 |
| 153 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 154 | 197 | 426 | 0 | 6970 | 0 |
| 155 | 197 | 442 | 0 | 5741 | 0 |
| 156 | 197 | 442 | 0 | 5738 | 0 |
| 157 | 197 | 499 | 0 | 6623 | 0 |
| 158 | 197 | 499 | 0 | 6621 | 0 |
| 159 | 197 | 499 | 0 | 6617 | 0 |
| 160 | 197 | 499 | 0 | 6619 | 0 |
| 161 | 197 | 499 | 0 | 5784 | 0 |
| 162 | 197 | 531 | 0 | 7111 | 0 |
| 163 | 197 | 531 | 0 | 7113 | 0 |
| 164 | 197 | 531 | 0 | 7115 | 0 |
| 165 | 197 | 531 | 0 | 7117 | 0 |
| 166 | 197 | 419 | 0 | 6293 | 0 |
| 167 | 228 | 419 | 1 | 6293 | 0 |
| 168 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4135 | 0 |
| 169 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4112 | 0 |
| 170 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4102 | 0 |
| 171 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4095 | 0 |
| 172 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4101 | 0 |
| 173 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4106 | 0 |
| 174 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4099 | 0 |
| 175 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4096 | 0 |
| 176 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4100 | 0 |
| 177 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4098 | 0 |
| 178 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 179 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4579 | 0 |
| 180 | 277 | 424 | 0 | 4586 | 0 |
| 181 | 198 | 418 | 0 | 4579 | 0 |
| 182 | 198 | 418 | 0 | 5443 | 0 |
| 183 | 198 | 419 | 0 | 4098 | 0 |
| 184 | 198 | 419 | 0 | 4145 | 0 |
| 185 | 198 | 419 | 0 | 6293 | 0 |
| 186 | 198 | 420 | 0 | 5001 | 0 |
| 187 | 198 | 420 | 0 | 4102 | 0 |
| 188 | 198 | 421 | 0 | 4285 | 0 |
| 189 | 198 | 421 | 0 | 4141 | 0 |
| 190 | 198 | 421 | 0 | 4142 | 0 |
| 191 | 198 | 421 | 0 | 4144 | 0 |
| 192 | 198 | 421 | 0 | 4225 | 0 |
| 193 | 198 | 421 | 0 | 5973 | 0 |
| 194 | 198 | 421 | 0 | 4099 | 0 |
| 195 | 198 | 421 | 0 | 4983 | 0 |
| 196 | 198 | 423 | 0 | 4112 | 0 |
| 197 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4106 | 0 |
| 198 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4135 | 0 |
| 199 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4099 | 0 |
| 200 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4095 | 0 |
| 201 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4098 | 0 |
| 202 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4101 | 0 |
| 203 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 204 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4102 | 0 |
| 205 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4100 | 0 |
| 206 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4586 | 0 |
| 207 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4579 | 0 |
| 208 | 198 | 424 | 0 | 4112 | 0 |
| 209 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 4394 | 0 |
| 210 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 4395 | 0 |
| 211 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 4861 | 0 |
| 212 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 5154 | 0 |
| 213 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 5100 | 0 |
| 214 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 4224 | 0 |
| 215 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 5152 | 0 |
| 216 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 5102 | 0 |
| 217 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 5785 | 0 |
| 218 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 4442 | 0 |
| 219 | 198 | 426 | 0 | 6970 | 0 |
| 220 | 198 | 442 | 0 | 5738 | 0 |
| 221 | 198 | 442 | 0 | 5741 | 0 |
| 222 | 198 | 499 | 0 | 6617 | 0 |
| 223 | 198 | 499 | 0 | 6619 | 0 |
| 224 | 198 | 499 | 0 | 6621 | 0 |
| 225 | 198 | 499 | 0 | 6623 | 0 |
| 226 | 198 | 499 | 0 | 5784 | 0 |
| 227 | 198 | 531 | 0 | 7117 | 0 |
| 228 | 198 | 531 | 0 | 7115 | 0 |
| 229 | 198 | 531 | 0 | 7113 | 0 |
| 230 | 198 | 531 | 0 | 7111 | 0 |
| 231 | 235 | 428 | 0 | 4280 | 0 |
| 232 | 235 | 428 | 0 | 5235 | 0 |
| 233 | 235 | 428 | 0 | 4442 | 0 |
| 234 | 235 | 428 | 0 | 6970 | 0 |
| 235 | 277 | 421 | 0 | 4983 | 0 |
| 236 | 277 | 421 | 0 | 4225 | 0 |
| 237 | 277 | 421 | 0 | 4142 | 0 |
| 238 | 277 | 421 | 0 | 4285 | 0 |
| 239 | 277 | 421 | 0 | 4144 | 0 |
| 240 | 277 | 421 | 0 | 4141 | 0 |
| 241 | 277 | 421 | 0 | 4099 | 0 |
| 242 | 277 | 421 | 0 | 5973 | 0 |
| 243 | 288 | 418 | 0 | 4579 | 0 |
| 244 | 288 | 418 | 0 | 5443 | 0 |
| 245 | 288 | 419 | 0 | 4098 | 0 |
| 246 | 288 | 419 | 0 | 4145 | 0 |
| 247 | 288 | 419 | 0 | 6293 | 0 |
| 248 | 288 | 420 | 0 | 5001 | 0 |
| 249 | 288 | 420 | 0 | 4102 | 0 |

Comment: A sample set of data, and your expected output from that sample set of data would be useful for people to be able to provide assistance.  Personally, I can see what you're likely trying to achieve, but without some actual data, it's difficult to visualise exactly how the query should be (and I'll be honest, I'm not going to take time myself to setup a sample dataset)

Comment: Hi - try creating a string of all the permission groups each user has, using STRING_AGG, and then see which users have the same strings

Comment: What exactly is your definition of: "users with the same set of permission groups" ? It is unclear what exactly one needs to compare here. Depending on the **combination** set, doing this on the database alone may be very difficult

Comment: What part does the "ItemOrganizationId" column play?

Comment: Can you also please tag your specific database server, and note the version?  I'm taking a guess that it's SQL Server, but I'm not entirely sure.  Plus, if it is SQL Server, then which version you are on will dictate some of the options available to you

Comment: @Craig: updated, sorry. ItemOrganizationId is a collection of actual items that tie to a permission group that the user has.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Basically we are trying to get a list of a permission groups based on usesrs so we can make suggestion on how roles should be setup (honestly, I think the wizard update my first part of my question and removed the roles part)

Comment: Sorry, you still didn't answer the question. Whether a permission group is defined by the whole set of columns values (ie: UserId, PermissionGroupId, CanModify, ItemOrganizationId) or any combination of the columns. An example of the answer I'm looking for: a set of permission for a given user is given by: same PermissionGroupId, CanModify and ItemOrganizationId. So if user 228 and 107 have the above combination they are considered a "set of permission groups". Because you didn't explain your goal (above), nor show from your sample data what is the desired output, we simply can't tell.

Comment: Do consider whether you can provide a [mre] i.e. the minimum amount of data required to demonstrate the issue. Thats a big list which makes it harder to grasp the question. And please show your desired results for the provided sample data.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: It is just UserId and PermissionGroupId. The other columns don't matter in this case. They are used for other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @NickW early in the comments:

After eliminating duplicate `UserId`/`PermissionGroupId` combinations, you can group by `UserId` and use `STRING_AGG()` to gather the `PermissionGroupId` values into an ordered comma separated list. After that, you can then group those results by combined group IDs and aggregate the UserIDs having the same group ID collection.

```
;WITH DistinctUserGroups AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT UEI.UserId, UEI.PermissionGroupId
    FROM UserEndItems UEI
),
UserGroupsCombined AS (
    SELECT
        DUG.UserId,
        COUNT(*) AS NGroups,
        STRING_AGG(DUG.PermissionGroupId, ',')
            WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY DUG.PermissionGroupId)
            AS GroupIdList
    FROM DistinctUserGroups DUG
    GROUP BY DUG.UserId
)
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS NUsers,
    STRING_AGG(UGC.UserId, ',')
        WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY UGC.UserId)
        AS UserIdList,
    UGC.NGroups,
    UGC.GroupIdList
FROM UserGroupsCombined UGC
GROUP BY UGC.NGroups, UGC.GroupIdList
ORDER BY UGC.GroupIdList
```

Sample results:

| NUsers | UserIdList | NGroups | GroupIdList |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 288 | 3 | 418,419,420 |
| 1 | 228 | 9 | 418,419,420,421,423,424,426,442,499 |
| 2 | 197,198 | 10 | 418,419,420,421,423,424,426,442,499,531 |
| 1 | 277 | 2 | 421,424 |
| 2 | 108,137 | 1 | 426 |
| 1 | 235 | 2 | 426,428 |
| 2 | 107,222 | 3 | 426,499,531 |

See [this db<>fiddlw](https://dbfiddle.uk/SHFwfu07).

Your sample data did not include the `PermissionGroups` table so the above just shows IDs. It should be a simple matter to include group names instead. You can also add `HAVING` conditions to eliminate singletons at both levels.